# What does the word "Hakim" sound and feel like?

Tags: meaning, semantics, phonetics

I really enjoy the connotations of words, particularly now because I'm looking for a name for something. I'd like to know what this word (**hakim**) sounds like to native English speakers.

**Obs:** If there's a foreigner and in your country this word is used and makes sense in a different context or it's pejorative, please let me know the points below.

- Is it good?
- Is it an easy to recognize word?
- Is it commonly used?
- In which context is this word used?
- What do you first remember when see ***hakim*** in a text, phrase, etc?

Comment: It sounds to me like an Arabic given name for a man. All names are the same to me, unless they're weird. _Hakim_ sounds normal to me. No connotations at all because it's not an English word.

Comment: Thanks @BillFranke for editing. Actually I didn't know hakim's etymology. I just found http://www.wordnik.com/words/hakim here and now everything seems clearer. =D

Comment: It is not a word I (British) recognise as English in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Indonesia...

1. Yes, it's good.
2. Yes, it is.
3. Yes, it is.
4. In Indonesia, 'Hakim' means the judge in laws trial. It is also a name for man. The word is from arabic, means 'king'
5. Law.

Comment: So you're understanding this word in Indonesian, but not in English?

Comment: @Mitch check my reply above and it's not Indonesian, but actually it has an Arabic origin.

Comment: "Hakim" or "Hakeem" or "हकीम" in Hindi means "Clinician" or "Doctor" usually without any medical degree.